# Add text to P or div on selecting the radio button

Tags: jquery

I have a sample work done in JSFiddle and I have updated the code by adding a radio button. If selected, I would like to add some text next to the selected radio button. When I clicked, it seems not even geting alert working. Could someone help on what I am doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/XRUX8/4/

```
 $('input[name=primaryAgent]:radio').click(function(){
    alert("test alert");
    $("#note").text("Helllo next by Primary");
 });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Its a duplicate this is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/f27YD/

Comment: i dont see no radio button !

Comment: @HusseinNazzal you need to click on the button.. :) See the fiddle. It is classic question, binding event on dynamically created element.

Comment: Button named radio :-)

Comment: aha .. sorry i saw the fiddle but couldn't locate the radio button code .. because of the too much line breaks .  :/

Comment: Problem fixed. Thank you all. I am new bee learing Jquery bootstratp CSS :). Thanks once again.

Comment: Small issue, why it is deleting remove button? Is theranyway I can keep the text and button aswell ?

Comment: Hello, If I add two names and when I click on either one of those radio buttons it is always updating the first <DIV> tag. I know this is due to dynamically creating elements and both may have same DIV ID and then first one get written. How can we track which radio button was click and write next by it? http://jsfiddle.net/XRUX8/10/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .on to bind events to dynamically generated elements.  Your event listener for the radio button should look like this.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name=primaryAgent]:radio',function(){
    alert("test alert");
    $("#note").text("Hello next by Primary");

});
```

Comment: Small issue, why it is deleting remove button? Is theranyway I can keep the text and button aswell

Comment: Nevermind, I chnaged it to DIV and butoon stays now. I wonder what is happening with P tag. Thanks